# Why is the Linux kernel still compiled with gnu89?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

Why is the Linux kernel still compiled with gnu89, which is many years ago?

Comment: In any case: coding standard is also very important. Do declaration outside loop, in line with the rest of code. You will see quickly the usefulness to have consistent coding.

Comment: Feel free  to update 15 million lines of code to use the newer compiler standard and fix all the bugs that creates, then submit the patch for review.

Answer (score 2):

Until 2018, the kernel supported being compiled using gcc 3.2. It was raised to gcc 4.9 in 2018 and now, mandating gcc 5.1 is being discussed, as you can see here: https://lore.kernel.org/linux-arm-kernel/CAK8P3a2J8fLjPhyV0XUeuRBdSo6rz1gU4wrQRyfzKQvwhf22ag@mail.gmail.com/

This would allow using -std=gnu11 and as Linus points out in https://lore.kernel.org/linux-arm-kernel/CAHk-=whnKkj5CSbj-uG_MVVUsPZ6ppd_MFhZf_kpXDkh2MAVRA@mail.gmail.com/ this would mainly bring variable declarations in for-loops.